# How to grep curl -I header information

Tags: linux, redirect, curl

I'm trying to get the redirect link from a site by using `curl -I` then `grep` to "location" and then `sed` out the location text so that I am left with the URL.

But this doesn't work. It outputs the URL to screen and doesn't put it

```
test=$(curl -I "http://www.redirectURL.com/" 2> /dev/null | grep "location" | sed -E 's/location:[ ]+//g')
echo "1..$test..2"
```

Which then outputs:

```
..2http://www.newURLfromRedirect.com/bla
```

What's going on?

Comment: Note that `--silent` or `-s` work as well as `2> /dev/null` (and are less typing).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @user353852 points out, you have a carriage return character in you output from `curl` that is only apparent when you try to `echo` any character after it. The `less` pager shows this up as <kbd>^M</kbd>

You can use `sed` to remove "control characters", like in this example:

```
% test=$(curl -I "http://www.redirectURL.com/" 2>|/dev/null | awk '/^Location:/ { print $2 }' | sed -e 's/[[:cntrl:]]//') && echo "1..${test}..2"
1..http://www.redirecturl.com..2
```

**Notes**:

I used `awk` rather than your `grep [...] | sed` approach, saving one process.

For me, `curl` returns the location in a line starting with 'Location:' (with a capital 'L'), if your version is really reporting it with a lowercase 'l', then you may need to change the regular expression accordingly.

Comment: Ah yes awk, I always forget about that command. Yea it's strange all the others start with a capital but not location: i'v added in [lL]ocation: so that my script will still working on a different distro :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

the "Location" http header starts with a capital L, try replacing that in your command.

**UPDATE**

OK, I have run both lines separately and each runs fine, except that it looks like the output from the curl command includes some control chars which is being captured in the variable.  When this is later printed in the echo command, the $test variable is printed followed by carriage return to set the cursor to the start of the line and then ..2 is printed over the top of 1..

Check out the $test variable in less:

```
echo 1..$test..2 | less
```

less shows:

```
1..http://www.redirectURL.com/^M..2
```

where ^M is the carriage return character.

Comment: Not mine, mine is "location:"

Comment: @user353852: Absolutely brilliant! Piping to `less` does highlight why "..2" is at the beginning of the line.

Comment: Ah yes I see it now, so thats the little beggar causing all the trouble.